# Sorting dict using tuple or list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

How can I sort dict keys using a tuple or a list and than return values?
For example, I have a dict:

```
d = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 3, 'c' : 5, d : '7'}
```

and a tuple:

```
t = ('d', 'b', 'c', 'a')
```

I would like to get a list of values, like:

```
[7, 3, 5, 1]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a question about sorting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [d[k] for k in t]
['7', 3, 5, 1]
```

or `map`:

```
>>> map(d.get, t)
['7', 3, 5, 1]
```

You can also create an `OrderedDict` using the items in `t`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dic = OrderedDict((k, d[k]) for k in t)
>>> dic.values()
['7', 3, 5, 1]
```